# User sign-up with email verification, and authentication in Ruby

Tags: ruby, authentication, openid, sinatra, rack

I'm trying to make a web app in Sinatra, and I was wondering if there was a good solution for user sign-up with email verification, as well as authentication - perhaps as rack middleware? OpenID support would be nice to have too.

I suppose I can roll my own, but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel. If I have to do so, can anyone point me to the libraries I might want to use, maybe even example code? I'm also worried I might end up forgetting to implement something important with signup/authentication, since I've never done this before.

In case I need a homemade solution, I've found [bcrypt-ruby](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/) for password encryption and [Sinatra::Mailer](http://github.com/foca/sinatra-mailer/tree/master) or [Pony](http://adam.blog.heroku.com/past/2008/11/2/pony_the_express_way_to_send_email_from_ruby/) for email. For signing on with OpenID support, there's [hancock](http://github.com/atmos/hancock/tree/master) and [hancock-client](http://github.com/atmos/hancock-client/tree/master), though I'm not entirely clear on usage and I don't actually need [single sign-on support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). Maybe I should just use [a ruby openid library](http://openidenabled.com/ruby-openid/)? Do I need anything else?

This is a pretty muddled question, but I hope someone more experienced can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). You'll need to implement the e-mail verification yourself, but it will provide you with a good foundation for supporting this.

> Authlogic can be
>   used in any ruby framework you want:
>   Rails, Merb, Sinatra, Mack, your own
>   framework, whatever. It’s not tied
>   down to Rails. It does this by
>   abstracting itself from these
>   framework’s controllers by using a
>   controller adapter. Thanks to Rack,
>   there is a defined standard for
>   controller structure, and that’s what
>   Authlogic’s abstract adapter follows.
>   So if your controller follows the rack
>   standards, you don’t need to do
>   anything.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. However, I can't figure out how to use it with Sinatra, since the examples are for rails...

Comment: I wrote an adapter to make authlogic work with sinatra. It's available as part of this template: http://github.com/ehsanul/Sinatra-Authlogic-Template/tree/master